# iPad hacked by landlady's son? How do I verify this? How can I keep him out?

Tags: ipad

I am borrowing someone's iPad 4. The iPad was set up by my landlord's son who lives out-of-state. I use my landlord's WiFi with her permission. My landlady mentioned that her son remotely controls her computer.

Note this: I once went to AT&T with the owner of the iPad. He wanted to change some setting on the iPad, maybe a password. He couldn't remember the original password. But he couldn't reset the password because the phone number he needed to know to have the password reset was the phone number of my landlady's son. He, the son, had entered his phone number instead of my friend's, the actual owner's phone number when setting up the iPad.

My question is, what else could he have done to make it possible to remotely control/hack into this iPad and how can I get him out?

I tried to see if he was remotely accessing this iPad by baiting him. I wrote and emailed to myself two different incendiary emails regarding him and his parents. Emailed to myself. Soon after the first email, I opened my iPad and this email flashed across the screen, then disappeared. What should have happened when I opened the iPad was this: I should have seen a near-empty screen with the words: slide to unlock; next to appear would be a screen with the keypad to unlock the iPad.

But this time, no. The incendiary email flashed across the screen and then disappeared.

After it disappeared, the slide-to-open screen appeared, the keypad screen appeared, then I had to go to the website for my email, I had to log into my email account-- a many-step process.

After I wrote the second incendiary email and emailed it to myself, this happened again. The email flashed across my screen as soon as I opened the iPad and disappeared.

Let me add that each time this happened, the particular email was not the last in line of emails written, nor the last of the emails read/accessed by me, so it's not as if the last email read/written was flashed across the screen upon opening.

Also, no other emails have ever flashed across the screen upon opening the iPad.

So, is the son of the landlord hacking this iPad?

If so, how can I get him out?

Comment: Have you tried wiping the device via iTunes?  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306